# Typescript question mark on function declaration

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, interface

I have recently encountered an interesting occurrence in typescript where I was not able to find a direct answer to online.

```
interface IClassInterface {
    optionOne: boolean;
    optionTwo?: string;
    optionThree?: () => void;
}
```

Now I understand that this is a simple interface which defines the types for a variable, class, etc. which may implement it and it indicates that the optionTwo as well as optionThree is an optional parameter/function.

However, what about this case?:

```
class ClassName {
    classFunctionOne() { }

    classFunctionTwo?() {
        console.log("This is function two")
    }
}
```

Why does typescript allow to declare an optional function inside this class if the function is declared? How can it be an optional function which is declared and possibly undefined if called from, for instance, in `classFunctionOne` ? Are there any use-cases for such situation?

Comment: Define absctract classes with optional functions which you can skip implementing it in derived classes.

Comment: Shouldn't the class be declared with the word `abstract` then? I believe that keyword is also used for methods and they can not be declared in that same class?

Comment: As far as I have noticed, running this script in react-native launches the application, but trying it out in a playground indicates an error during compile time that the question mark is an unexpected token in javascript. Can this potentially be a bug if it does not have a use case and can not be compiled?

Comment: The bug you found will be [fixed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/34954)  in the next version of TS.

Comment: This feels like an opinion question... optional methods are presumably used the same way optional properties are used: when it's possible for it not to be defined.  You can make `class Foo {bar?: string = "hey"}` also.  In your above example you can make `class Sub extends ClassName { classFunctionTwo = undefined; }` and it's a valid extension because the method is optional in the superclass. I'm not sure if you want a list of all ways one could use this feature.  Is there something non-opinion-like you want here?